# CSS styling - how to put these two div boxes adjacent

Tags: css

I have two divs inside a div, I want them both adjacent to each other with a margin of 10px or so separating them but instead they appear one above the other.

```
 <div>
     <div class="post" id="fact">
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="sortbar">
    </div>

 </div>
```

Here is my styling:

```
 #fact{width:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;} #sortbar{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

The whole code is within a div container wrapper with these properties:

```
 #wrapper {
 float:left;
margin-top:10px;
 width:728px;
 }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two options (choose one or the other but not both).

- set `float: left;` on both `#fact` and `#sortbar`
- set `display: inline-block;` on  both `#fact` and `#sortbar`

The second option is better because you don't have to fix the clearing and such, as well as the fact that inline-block works a lot better layout-wise than left floating.

Answer (score 5):

See this **[working example](http://jsbin.com/ayixo3)**. You can copy and paste this HTML & CSS and try it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CSS styling - how to put these two div boxes adjacent</title>

<style type="text/css">
.wrapper .post {
-moz-border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px;
border:1px solid silver;
float:left;
margin:10px;
min-height:100px;
padding:5px;
width:200px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h4>CSS styling - how to put these two div boxes adjacent</h4>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="post">
    <div>
    Browse (<a href="http://www.google.com/ncr">Google</a>)
    </div>
    <div>
    This is a Div
    </div>
    <div>
    This is a Div
    </div>
    <div>
    This is a Div
    </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <div>
    Browse (<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/">Wikepedia</a>)
    </div>
    <div>
    This is another Div
    </div>
    <div>
    <div>
    This is another Div
    </div>
    <div>
    This is another Div
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it...

```
#fact {
    width:200px; 
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
} 
#sortbar {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;`:

```
#fact, #sortbar{
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

[See the working demo here.](http://jsbin.com/exeto3)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your #fact and #sortbar divs still have the default 'block' display type which, in simple terms, will put your divs in their own horizontal space.  The other answers here show how to use "float" to solve your issue.

Here's some linkage for you:

box model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html
display css property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp
float tutorial: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Dan