# How to arrange/align two paragraphs into boxes

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS styling - how to put these two div boxes adjacent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540976/css-styling-how-to-put-these-two-div-boxes-adjacent)

I have to 2 paragraphs:

```
Para 1

Para 2
```

How can I make it appear like:

```
Para1   Para2
```

Both in their own space and box.

[image: This is what I want.]

```
   <div>
  <div class="block" id="profile">
  <h3>Professional Profile</h3>
  <p>Knowledge in all aspects of web application development. 
  My Skills to solve programming errors gets the job
  faster. Proficient in performance tuning database applications.</p>
  </div>
```

What do I do in here?

```
  <div class="block" id ="contact">
  <p>
  <h3> Contact</h3>
  <address>Written by W3Schools.com<br /><a href="mailto:rjohn5854@howardcc.edu">
  Email Me!!!</a><br />Address: Box 3223,City<br />Phone:6750</address>
  <p>
  </div>
  </div>

CSS


  div.block p  {
      display: inline-block;    
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Seriously, man, do you think that SO is a no-cost freelance board?

Comment: Dude, Chill.... I attached a picture of what I have so far.

Comment: a lot of people do XD some are just very new to VS and making websites and don't know how else to learn. People are used to yahoo answers i guess :/

Comment: Exactly, I did search for a duplicate ..couldn't find any so I open this question.

Comment: change your class from div.block p to just .block and it should fix it.

Comment: also try defining the width of each div such as 300px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css:

```
.align-profile,
.align-contact
{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top; //also can try other align settings
   width: 45%;
}

.align-contact
{
   margin-left: 30px; //also try depending on the spacing you want between them
}
```

In your html:

```
<div class="align-profile">
   <h2>Profile</h2>
   para1
</div>
<div class="align-contact">
   <h2>Contact</h2>
   para2
</div>
```

*Note div's or paragraphs must be aligned to have this happen. If you put a div inside a div or a paragraph inside a paragraph it will not work.*

Comment: Are you having trouble implementing the suggested changes?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`display: inline-block` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display) or similar:

```
p { display: inline-block; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eN39E/2)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML paragraph tag

is block element, so it occupies all width of parent element. If you can arrange two

block in one line, you need change block behavior to inline. Use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` for it.